# How do I join multiple csv file while reading them in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have 2 csv files. (Actually I have multiple files in a directory but for simplicity I give 2 example csv files.)

first.csv:

| 1 | a |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 4 | d |

second.csv:

| 1 | a |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | b |
| 3 | c |
| 5 | d |

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Example") \
.master("local[2]") \
.getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField("x", IntegerType(), True),
                        StructField("y", StringType(), True),
                         StructField("z", StringType(), True)])

df = spark.read.load(["first.csv", "second.csv"], header=None, schema=schema, format="csv")
```

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | null |
| 2 | b | null |
| 3 | c | null |
| 4 | d | null |
| 1 | a | null |
| 2 | b | null |
| 3 | c | null |
| 5 | d | null |

But I want this output:

| x | y | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | a |
| 2 | b | b |
| 3 | c | c |
| 4 | d | NaN |
| 5 | NaN | d |

How can I get this output while reading files in a directory ? What should I change ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files can be read separately, and joined with `outer` join. On Scala (guess, can be translated to Python easily):

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("x", IntegerType),
  StructField("value", StringType)
))
val first = spark.read.schema(schema).csv("first.csv")
val second = spark.read.schema(schema).csv("second.csv")

val result = first
    .withColumnRenamed("value", "y")
    .join(second.withColumnRenamed("value", "z"), Seq("x"), "outer")
```

Result:

```
+---+----+----+
|x  |y   |z   |
+---+----+----+
|1  |a   |a   |
|2  |b   |b   |
|3  |c   |c   |
|4  |d   |null|
|5  |null|d   |
+---+----+----+
```

Note: If nulls have to be replaces with `NaN`, `na.fill` can be used:

```
result.na.fill("NaN")
```